# WooCommerce Subscriptions + WP Funds

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I need to add funds to a user's account via **Account Funds** on the successful renewal of their membership via **WooCommerce Subscriptions**.

Is there a way to do this via WP functions? if so how would I do this? I have tried with the following with no luck.

```
add_action('processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_add_funds', 10, 2);

function custom_add_funds($user_id) {

    // get current user's funds
    $funds = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', true );

    // add £40
    $funds = $funds + 40;

    // add funds to user
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', $funds );

}
```

Account Funds: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/account-funds/

Subscriptions: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/